# Clicking an element in Selenium 2 webdriver with Python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I have looked at the Selenium documentation and can not find an example of clicking on an element. I inspected an element named attatchments.

Everytime I attempt to click the element Python gives me an error usually one of these:

> {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.24.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 155, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.24.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 147, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"name","selector":"add individuals"}'

Here is the code I am trying:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("attatchments")
elem.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know element id then you can get it as

```
element = driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="element_id")
```

Or

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("element_id")
```

and then use `element.click()`

You can go through this link to know the methods in Webdriver class: http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html

Comment: elem = driver.find_element("attatchments")
elem.click()        WHen I inspect I see attatchments for input. shows exception class Unsupported locator startegy attatchments? Any help is appreciated do i need a wait? if so how do i write a quick wait or is it another problem all together.